# Slide WebView up on top of hidden view - Swift

Tags: swift, uiwebview, uiviewanimation

So far, I have gotten it so that when the user opens the side menu, the view will hide, however, once I have tried animating using the below code, the animation/transformation did not take place.

Code(WebViewTst is the WebView)(animView is the view that was hidden)(height constraint *was* the constraint for the view before I deleted it):

```
    if(revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.right){


        animView.isHidden = true


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.WebViewTst.layer.zPosition = 1
            self.heightConstraint.constant = 595

        })

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call self.view.layoutIfNeeded() after the layout constraint.

Another way to animate is using a transition. U can make this animation block:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    self.WebViewTst.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 595;
}
```

(I'm not sure if u need to make dy -595 or 595)

When u want to reset the WebViewTst position, simply call:

```
self.WebViewTst.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
```

Comment: This worked for me. Just changed the 595 to -65 and it worked smoothly. Thanks!